# jupyter server : not started, no kernel in vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

i am trying to use jupyter notebooks from vs code and installed jupyter notebook extension and i am using (base)conda environment for execution.
while this happened

```
Error: Jupyter cannot be started. Error attempting to locate jupyter:
at A.startServer (c:\Users\DELL\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.2.63990\out\client\extension.js:1:784356)
at async A.ensureServerAndNotebookImpl (c:\Users\DELL\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.2.63990\out\client\extension.js:1:783811)
at async A.ensureServerAndNotebook (c:\Users\DELL\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.2.63990\out\client\extension.js:1:783612)
at async A.submitCode (c:\Users\DELL\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.2.63990\out\client\extension.js:1:780564)
at async A.reexecuteCell (c:\Users\DELL\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.2.63990\out\client\extension.js:75:879318)
```

[image: status of jupyter notebook]

how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: I restarted VSCode and somehow this fixed it.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem when I installed Visual Studio Code and tried to run some Python code from a jupyter notebook on my fresh Ubuntu 18.04.

How I solved it:

1. Make sure you have installed the Jupyter Extension in VS Code. (for those who don't read the SO question :))
2. Press `Command+Shift+P` to open a new command pallete
3. Type `>Python: Select Intepreter to start jupyter notebook server`
4. Open the notebook again

And it worked fine. Hope it works for you.

Comment: now i have only below one
`>Jupyter: Select Intepreter to start jupyter notebook server`

Answer (score 20):

I have several versions of Python installed. It happened the same thing to me and I have fixed it this way.
Ctrl+Shift+p and select Python: Select Interpreter to start Jupyter server
[image]

Then, select the version under the Visual Studio Code
[image]

Nothing will happen and then press again Ctrl+Shift+p and select 
Python: Create new blank Jupyter Notebook. And it works

I have even set the Python version to 3.8 at the bottom and it worked too with the new features print(a:=4) despite the fact that the version I have chosen was 3.7.5. Nevertheless, I have to lunch VS Code from Anaconda Navigator.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

1. **Press**  `Command+Shift+P` on mac, `Ctrl+Shift+p` on windows
2. **Type** `Jupyter: Select Interpreter to start Jupyterserver`
3. It would show you a dropdown of **python** versions installed.
4. I chose **python 3.7.5** and it worked for me you can choose the python version installed on your machine.

Comment: How if at number three, it didn't show any, yet using `jupyter kernelspec list`, there are some kernel. Restarting VSCode does help, but it is a hassle.

Comment: `Type Jupyter: Select Interpreter to start Jupyterserver`  this command is not found. It would help to provide more information on the devcontainer setup that resulted in this command being available

Answer (score 11):

I have seen all possible solutions but not work, finally I just upgrade `jupyter`,`notebook`,and `jupyterlab`,like `pip3 install -U jupyterlab`, and I can choose the kernel in VScode!

Comment: yes! Make sure all of your dependencies are installed first. `pip` installing the above fixed my errors

Answer (score 4):

I tried the following:

1. Press `Command + SHIFT + P`
2. Type  `Python: Select Interpreter to start Jupyterserver`

Hope this answer was helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Making sure that in VS Code settings.json

`"python.condaPath": "C:\\Program Files\\miniconda3\\Scripts\\conda.exe"`

is pointing to the correct directory. It solved it for me.

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar issue quite often in VS Code, sometimes I can't get the kernel from my virtual enviroment (instead, VS Code only finds other venvs that are not related to my current project).

I tried reloading *the window, selecting interpreter to start jupyter, reloading the VS Code itself*, but **nothing worked**.

In case all the above and the other answers fail, try that, it worked for me:

1. Ctrl+Shift+P
2. Jupyter: Filter kernels
3. Select only the kernel you want (in my case, my venv)
4. Go on "Select Kernel" directly on the notebook UI;
5. Select your right kernel.

It is weird that the venv kernel appears on "Filter Kernels", but not always appears on the kernel list. But doing this might solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

just fix this by add

"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": false,

to settings.json

hopes this help.

Answer (score 2):

just had the same issue and it did not help to update the interpreter within vscode.
What helped was: Check your dependencies within pip! It seems that new dependencies came up with the latest update of python, which are not installed. For me this was pygments:

**jupyter-console 6.2.0 requires pygments, which is not installed.**

Linux solution step-by-step:

```
xyz@xyz-pc-ubuntu:~$ pip3 check
qtconsole 4.7.6 requires pygments, which is not installed.
nbconvert 5.6.1 requires pygments, which is not installed.
jupyter-console 6.2.0 requires pygments, which is not installed.
ipython 7.18.1 requires pygments, which is not installed.

xyz@xyz-pc-ubuntu:~$ pip3 install pygments
Successfully installed pygments-2.7.2
```

Afterwards, jupyter found the updated python interpreter automatically.

Answer (score 2):

i've stumbled upon this post, since i had a similar issue.
provided that my context was different, since i was ***working remotely on a linux server***, even if i selected the right interpreter (via `shift+ctrl+P` "Select Interpreter to start Jupyter server") the kernel remained unactive.
i've checked the installed dependencies inside the venv and tried to switch virtual environment to make it work.. kept on reloading the server, reloading the window.. no way.

eventually, a tiny fancy detail arouse my attention: the **"Jupyter server : remote" label in the bottom right**.
and tadaa : that was my issue. I've selected "default", letting VSCode starting  a server on the local (remote) host, and then the interpeter / kernel was enabled.

hope it can help anyone stuck on the same issue.[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had the server working in 3.7.6, but i wanted to use >3.8.0 versions too. After multiple attempts, which failed, I decided to:

1. Uninstall 3.8.5, and delete the folder in the installation directory.
2. Uninstall VSCode too.
3. Restart the PC, and re-install Python and VSCode.
   As a result, the Jupyter server initiated based on the latest version of Python automatically.

I hope this helps too!
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the extension had to be reloaded, and indeed it read *Reload required*.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem is that VSCode can't find the kernel, even in using the select interpreter option.

The most reliable solution that I can find and currently used is:

1. Install without cache:

   ```
   pip install jupyter notebook jupyterlab pyzmq --upgrade --no-cache-dir
   ```
2. Restart VSCode

---

Another extra safety step is to uninstall first and followed with `pip cache purge`

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the ["Python Extension Pack"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=donjayamanne.python-extension-pack&ssr=false#review-details) in vsc.
2. Then select the correct conda environment.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Manjaro Linux and what helped me was to install the code-features package from AUR-repository:

```
pamac search -a code-features
pamac build code-features
```

First step  is not necessary, just to confirm package is found in aur repo. Maybe helps with other arch based distros, too.

After that i could select the interpreter with Ctrl+Shift+p and select "Python: Select Interpreter to start Jupyter server".

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Just reinstalled the Jupyter Notebook extension in VS and it fixed my problem.

Answer (score -1):

For me uninstalling the Jupyter extension, closing VS code and then reinstalling it worked. Not a really great solution, but the only one that worked for me. Hope that may help someone.

Answer (score -1):

I had a comparable problem when trying to run **a jupyter notebook on a remote server**. The problem was solved by installing the **Python Extension** on this particular server from the extensions menu in VSCode. After that, the correct kernel was automatically chosen in the jupyter notebook and I could run everything smoothly.

Answer (score -1):

Fix this by going to settings and search for Environment, Under Extensions you'll find Python , Under python you can see a option called Python>Terminal : Activate Environment (Uncheck this box)

Then you can change your python interpreter to whichever version you like

hope this helps

Answer (score -2):

In my case the output of a cell was very big and got stuck on loading. Clearing the output of the cells worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

I had disabled the Jupyter extension, and enabling it solved the issue.

Answer (score -2):

I faced this issue with this v2023.5.1001582324 version of jupyter vs code extension, i revert it back to old version and it fixed it.
[image]