# VS Code Jupyter Notebook: Python Not Started

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have been using Jupyter Notebook on VS Code for months now without problems but yesterday the files stopped working. When I try to run a cell, the loading star sign shows up (so it is running believe) but it's stuck on that.

I tried running the same file on a local Jupyter Notebook and it works perfectly. Its some issue with VS Code settings/extensions.

[image]
The line at the top says Jupyter Server: local (but is red for some reason) and Python: Not Started is displayed.

[This issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60330837/jupyter-server-not-started-no-kernel-in-vs-code) was similar but it had a "no kernel" problem. Also, the answers in this post mention using the Command Palatte (Cmd+Shift+P) and selecting "Python: Select Interpreter to start Jupyter server".

However, this option is not shown for me. I tried following the steps regardless and it did not help.

[image: Pyhon Command Palatte]

Comment: Do you happen to have multiple Python interpreter versions on your machine?

Comment: Please try to click the python kernel on the upper right of Jupyter and select the required python kernel environment. In addition, please try to reinstall the "Python" extension and "Jupyter" extension and reload VS Code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description, it is recommended that you try the following:

1. Please try to click the python kernel at the top right of Jupyter and select the desired python kernel environment.

   [image]
2. Please check in the VS Code terminal whether "ipykernel" is already installed in the python environment you are currently using: (`pip show ipykernel`)

   [image]
3. Please try to reinstall the "Python" extension and the "Jupyter" extension and then reload VS Code.

Reference: [Jupyter Notebooks in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support).

Comment: I encountered "no kernel" issue. Following Step 3 to uninstall python and jupyter extensions from vscode then reinstalling is the solution for me.