# VScode with Jupiter Notebook: local jupyter server not connect and kernel not started

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am working on a Linux remote server and I am trying to use jupyter notebooks from VScode when I meet this problem. Here is what I've done:

1. I've installed jupyter notebook extension;
2. I am using a conda virtual environment with python3.6.5;
3. I **DID** install ipykernel with conda (also tried pip);
4. I **DID** install jupyter with conda (also tried pip);

When I finish the steps above, an issue in a [similar post:jupyter server : not started, no kernel in vs code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60330837/jupyter-server-not-started-no-kernel-in-vs-code) occured and I did what the most-voted answer said but my top right tab still said that the local jupyter server is NOT connected and the kernel is not started, like this:

> Jupyter Server: local [red inconnected plug] **|** :Not Started

Also, the bottom right bar inform me that VSCode was trying to start the server, but seemed never to succeed.

Could anybody help me with this?

Comment: Welcome! As a new user, take the [tour] and read [ask]. Please also read the descriptions of the tags that you applied and remove the one that doesn't apply. Further, check if your screenshots can't be represented as text, so that they can be searched and found easily. Apropos, searching for an error message online also helps getting an idea what it means.

Comment: Thank U @Ulrich Eckhardt for your advice, I've learned more about how SO community works!
and here for this question, I solve it by upgrading VSCode from 1.48 to 1.63, updating and reloading all packages, especially jupyter and python. It works very well by now, hope to help sb who meet the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. Reinstalling extensions and VSCode doesn't help.
I solved it by installing the Jupyter extension to another version (older or prerelease are fine). Then it shows up. I guess it's some hidden cache not cleared.